# how to implement flutter text animation, like poweoff button text animation in apple iPhones?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

Iam working on a flutter project, and i need to animate a text, initially the text is black , and then i need to a white color should be slided over the black text and it turns white, like overlaying the text, and it after changing it into white, it again turns black, it is like a serializing black with white, I mean just like iphone power button text animation, how to implement this concept in flutter?

When I used animation controller, to do this, it is actually turning all black text into white, and repeating the same, but i need white color just like an overlay to the black text, which is passing through the text repeatedly like power button text animation in Apple iPhone.

[image: text animation model in iPhone]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) package hope its help to you.

Refer below minimal code use `ColorizeAnimatedText` Widget

```
// Declartion

const colorizeColors = [
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.red,
];

const colorizeTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 50.0,
  fontFamily: 'Horizon',
);

// UI

return SizedBox(
  width: 250.0,
  child: AnimatedTextKit(
    animatedTexts: [
      ColorizeAnimatedText(
        'Larry Page',
        textStyle: colorizeTextStyle,
        colors: colorizeColors,
      ),
    ],
    isRepeatingAnimation: true,
    onTap: () {
      print("Tap Event");
    },
  ),
);
```

[Result Screen](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aagarwal1012/Animated-Text-Kit/master/display/colorize.gif):

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't help, this was not i hoped for

Comment: You want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWFWG.jpg) image button?

Comment: that's what iam trying to implement, there is animation going on inside that text, 'slide to power off'.

Comment: Try [action_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/action_slider) package if you want above image button

Comment: button is not the problem, it is the animation inside it